# Rails json Request are slow

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing an angularjs Application with Rails as Backend. It is hosted by DigitalOccean the smallest Server. On my Production System its only me testing right now. The problem is the requests take quite long and i can't figure out where the time is lost.

For Example

I make a json request to the backend. It takes around 500 ms. The request is gzipped. On the rails site i use rabl for the json response. My ping to the server is around 30 ms

The rails request renders on the server in 100 ms.

Where is the time of 400 ms spent? Any ideas? I have two screenshots one from chrome timing and the rails log.

- Rails Version 4.1.4
- Ruby 2.1.0
- nginx 1.6.0
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Postgres 9.2
- Angularjs 1.2.21
- unicorn

[image: log from unicorn]

[image: Chrome Timeline]

Comment: The timing screenshot is just for the GET /models request? Try to disable gzip because your VPS server might not be getting all the CPU it needs for that. Also, try testing locally with wget/curl.